# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to. (useStream doesn't close the stream)

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

In my `HookWidget`, I call:

```dart
final myData = useStream<MyData>(service.getDataStream(), initialData: {});
```

Unfortunately, when going back to the same screen/ navigating, I get `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`. This is probably because the previous stream does not get closed, and can't be listened to again.

**Why doesn't `useStream` close the stream**, or do I have to do it (how?, its created in the build method so it can be closed in dispose)? The `service` contains a `StreamController`:

```dart
class Service {
    final _dataController = StreamController<MyData>();
    
    Stream<Data> getDataStream() {
    return _dataController.stream;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably be using StreamProvider.autoDispose to create and hold your stream.

Comment: If you pushed same route twice and the stream is a singleton, that error may occurs.
`useStream` cancels subscription well.